# loading external script on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

There few external scripts loading on my website. for example, this Facebook Page Like Widget script. I don't want to load it until the user scrolls down to a certain position or at least a user scrolls. How can I achieve this with jquery or ajax or something?

```
connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js
```

```
             <script>
                    (function() {
                        var loadFB = function (d, s, id) {
                            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                            js = d.createElement(s);
                            js.onload = function() {
                                // After FB Page plugin is loaded, the height of its container changes.
                                // We need to notify theme about that so elements like eg. sticky widgets can react
                                FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function () {
                                    jQuery('body').trigger('g1PageHeightChanged');
                                });
                            };
                            js.id = id;
                            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
                            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                        };

                                                loadFB(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
                                            })();
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scroll event for this refer [docs](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an event that triggers when You reach a certain div:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       var heightT = $('.your-div').offset().top,
           outerH = $('.your-div').outerHeight(),
           windowH = $(window).height(),
           wS = $(this).scrollTop();

       if (wS > (heightT+outerH-windowH-200)){
          //add Your script here
       }
});
```

By calculating the screen height and the place of the div.

Don't have all Your code so can only guide You to the solution of "how to".

Please attach the rest if You need more help!